# Is there a way, using wmic, to reverse engineer which volume maps to which partition(s)?

Tags: windows, cmd, wmi, wmic

Problem.. I only have access to wmic... Lame I know.. but need to figure out which volume corresponds to what partition(s) which correspond to what disk.. I know how to correspond which partition corresponds to what disk because the disk id is directly in the results of the wmic query.  However, the first part of the problem is more difficult.  How to correlate which volume belongs to which partitions?..

Is there a way, using wmic, to reverse engineer which volume maps to which partition(s)?

If so how would this query look?

Comment: `wmic partition get diskindex,index` is the nearest thing that I could find. It tells you for every partition, where it's located, but gives no hint to identify the partition other than size and startingoffset. Sadly there is no link to drive letters or to `wmic logicaldisk` or `wmic diskdrive`, which are not guaranteed to have the same order.

Comment: @Stephan:  Thank you for at least understanding the second part of the problem.  The issue here is that I have many partitions of a large disk being used for many things, and now I have no way to correlate which partition matches which volume because windows doesn't seem to have a clear defined way of telling me where volumes reside.

Comment: I found a power shell solution.. However no wmic solution.. I guess I can use the power shell solution should I really need to.  However, it seems like it should be easy enough to translate this into command line.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/4579b83c-3ca6-444d-93cd-9c9f45a36dc0/mapping-the-volume-guid-to-the-physical-disk-and-partion-im-stuck?forum=ITCG

Answer (score 1):

```
wmic logicaldisk get name, volumename
```

for more info use wmic logicaldisk get /?

Comment: this gives only the logical disks ( = partitions), but not which partitions (logical disks) resides on which physical drive.

Comment: @Vairis : This is a step in the correct direction but after intensive investigation, the information returned by the virtualdisk in wmic does not link any volumes to to partitions and doesn't eve list all of the volumes if a mount point in stead of a drive letter has been provided.

Comment: @Stephan : In the partitions listed by wmic, It is clear by the disk index and the drive index what partitions correlate to which drive.. I am failing to make the connection of which volumes correlate to which partitions.

Comment: can you see those disks physically? then you could use volumeserialnumber switch and find disks in the rack

Comment: and have you tried combining info from wmic diskdrive with what you get from wmic logicaldisk ?

Comment: @Vairis : I believe that you misunderstand the question.. I can easily get the disk serial number and physically locate the disks.  The issue is finding out which logical volume contains which partitions on which disks on windows.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is with `diskpart` from a command prompt:

```
C:\>diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.10586

Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: TIMSPC

DISKPART> select disk 0

Disk 0 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> detail disk

HGST HTS725050A7E630 *(Note: This is the Model of my hard disk)*
Disk ID: 00C942C7
Type   : SATA
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1F02)#ATA(C00T00L00)
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : Yes
Pagefile Disk  : Yes
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : Yes
Clustered Disk  : No

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0         System       NTFS   Partition    350 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 1     C   OSDisk       NTFS   Partition    464 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 2                      NTFS   Partition    843 MB  Healthy    Hidden

DISKPART> exit

Leaving DiskPart...

C:\>
```

You have access to a command line since you have access to WMIC, so this method *should* work.

---

Based on the comments below:
No, there is no way to use WMIC to determine with 100% accuracy exactly which partition corresponds to which partition on a specific drive. The problem with determining this information via WMI is that not all drives are basic drives. Some disks may be [dynamic disks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363785(v=vs.85).aspx#dynamic_disks) containing a RAID volume that spans multiple drives. Some may be a complete hardware implemented abstraction like a storage array (for example, a p410i RAID controller in an HP ProLiant). In addition, there are multiple partitioning schemes (eg [UEFI/GPT vs BIOS/MBR](http://techpp.com/2013/12/19/uefi-vs-bios/)). WMI is however independent of its environment. That is, it doesn't care about the hardware. It is simply another form of abstraction that provides a common interface model that [unifies and extends existing instrumentation and management standards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811552.aspx).

To get the level of detail you desire will require a tool that can interface at a much lower level like the driver for the device and hope that the driver provides the information you need. If it doesn't, you will be looking at very low level programming to interface with the device itself...essentially creating a new driver that provides the information you want. But based on your limitation of only having command line access, Diskpart is the closest prebuilt tool you will find.

> 1. There are volumes which do not have traditional letters.

And? Diskpart can select disk, partitions, and volumes based on the number assigned. The drive letter is irrelevant.

> 3. At no point in disk part is any kind of ID listed which allows a user to 100% know which partition they are dealing with when they reference a volume.

Here is an example from one of my servers with two 500gb hard drives. The first in the Boot/OS drive. The second has 2gb of unallocated space.

```
DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  ------
  Volume 0         System       NTFS   Partition    350 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 1     C   OSDisk       NTFS   Partition    465 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 2     D   New Volume   NTFS   Partition    463 GB  Healthy

DISKPART> select volume 2

Volume 2 is the selected volume.

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          465 GB      0 B
* Disk 1    Online          465 GB  2049 MB

DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
* Partition 1    Primary            463 GB  1024 KB

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  ------
  Volume 0         System       NTFS   Partition    350 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 1     C   OSDisk       NTFS   Partition    465 GB  Healthy    Boot
* Volume 2     D   New Volume   NTFS   Partition    463 GB  Healthy

DISKPART>
```

Notice the asterisks? Those denote the active disk, partition, and volume. While these are not the ID you require to allow a user to 100% know which partition they are dealing with, you can at least clearly see that Volume 2 (D:) is on Partition 1 of Disk 1.

> 2. There are volumes that are RAW disks which is essentially saying.. this is a raw disk and I want to find out where these raw disks are at.

As you can see after I have created a volume with no file system on the 2gb of free space, this does not make any difference:

```
DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  -------
  Volume 0         System       NTFS   Partition    350 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 1     C   OSDisk       NTFS   Partition    465 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 2     D   New Volume   NTFS   Partition    463 GB  Healthy
  Volume 3                      RAW    Partition   2048 MB  Healthy

DISKPART> select volume 3

Volume 3 is the selected volume.

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  -------
  Volume 0         System       NTFS   Partition    350 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 1     C   OSDisk       NTFS   Partition    465 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 2     D   New Volume   NTFS   Partition    463 GB  Healthy
* Volume 3                      RAW    Partition   2048 MB  Healthy

DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary            463 GB  1024 KB
* Partition 2    Primary           2048 MB   463 GB

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          465 GB      0 B
* Disk 1    Online          465 GB  1024 KB
```

> 4. The reason that I am using wmic is because I need to script out many disk ops. Have you ever tried to script out getting information from diskpart?

No, but it *is* [scriptable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn614984(v=ws.11).aspx).

In your sample data, you can enumerate the disk, volumes, and partitions. By looping through each object and selecting it, you can create a map of which volume is on which partition and which drive contains that partition. Diskpart may not provide 100% of the data you need 100% of the time with 100% of the accuracy you want, but it is the closest command line tool you are going to find to meet your goal.

Comment: This is not a solution.
Please examine the data garnered from me running disk part.
1. There are volumes which do not have traditional letters.
2.  There are volumes that are RAW disks which is essentially saying.. this is a raw disk and I want to find out where these raw  disks are at.
3.  At no point in disk part is any kind of ID listed which allows a user to 100% know which partition they are dealing with when they reference a volume.
4.  The reason that I am using wmic is because I need to script out many disk ops. Have you ever tried to script out getting information from diskpart?

Comment: To help in the description of why this will not work..
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=748E20FF738B84A7!200&authkey=!AOiQicfCXA1QaLg&v=3&ithint=photo%2cjpg